# Adding Custom Metadata to a Serialized XML Document - .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml, .net-core

I am currently serializing my XML objects like this:

```cs
public static string Serialize<T>(T value) {
  XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

  using (var sww = new StringWriter())
  {
    using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(sww))
    {
      xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, value);
    }

    return sww.ToString();
  }
}
```

However, I want some custom MetaData in my XML document:

```
<myXML>
  <META>
    <timeStamp>Sunday, November 11, 2020</timeStamp>
    ...
  </META>
  <DATA>
    // Serialized Object
  </DATA>
</myXML>
```

Is there anyway I can achieve this without manually building the whole document with something like `XDocument`, or adding fields to all of my objects?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Sorry, I fixed a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it.

For example

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConApp
{
    public class Data
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Meta
    {
        [XmlElement("timeStamp")]
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

        // other meta properties
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var data = new Data { Id = 5, Name = "Five" };
            var meta = new Meta { Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow };

            var result = Serialize(data, meta);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        public static string Serialize<T>(T value, Meta meta)
        {
            var metaSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Meta));
            var typeSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true };

            using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, settings))
            {
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("myXML");

                metaSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, meta);
                typeSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, value);

                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
                xmlWriter.Flush();

                return stringWriter.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```